# How can I allow NULL values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how can I allow NULL values in the following code below along with keeping `WHERE username  = '$username'`.

here is the mysql code.

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM users 
 WHERE username  = '$username'
 AND user_id <> '$user_id'"
```

I'm trying to check for usernames with the same username but I want all users to have a NULL value if they want.

Comment: It would help if your question was more specific. NULL values for what column? user_id?

Comment: how is this SQL injection and how to protect?

Comment: @peak: http://xkcd.com/327/ and http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: @peakUC: You need to escape username and user_id, or you need to use prepared statements. It's sql injection because someone can set $username to something like "'; DROP TABLE users;" and the RDBMS will happily execute the DROP statement.

Comment: can u give an example on how to stop an SQL injection in my code? an example would be nice :)

Comment: @peak: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: I wont need it here in this part of the code would I?

Comment: @peak: you do if `$username` is client-controlled input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650043/php-mysql-username-submit-problem how is this code?

Comment: @peakUC: The code in that question is vulnerable. You must escape username before you create it as part of the SQL query.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, I escaped the username before its entered thanks though.

Comment: That's not very clear. You want to find all other users who share a username with the current user or don't have one, as Billy O'Neal's answer would do? I'm mystified as to why ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM users 
 WHERE (username ='$username' OR username IS NULL)
 AND user_id <> '$user_id'
```